# React-Redux and Utility class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to write a utility class that gets its data from an API call made in a Redux Action. `jobActions.getJobs()`
OR
just access the data that has been written to the Redux state `this.props.jobList`

But this is a simple class with no props passed to it. And I cannot access the getJobs() function outside of the class

Error: "Property 'props' does not exist on type 'typeof JobsUtil'."

How do I get this to work?

```
export class JobsUtil {
    // get jobs from API
    public static getJobs(): Array<IDropDownOptions> {
        const jobsList = this.props.jobActions.getJobs()
        return jobsList;    
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        jobList: state.toJS().jobList
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        jobActions: bindActionCreators<any, Dispatch>(jobActions, dispatch),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(JobsUtil as any)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` is designed to interact with a React component.  You cannot `connect` any other type of class.

```
Argument of type 'typeof JobsUtil' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'typeof JobsUtil' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
    Type 'JobsUtil' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<never, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.
```

Typescript should have given you the above error when you passed `JobsUtil` as an argument.  You suppressed the error by writing `JobsUtil as any` which is an assertion that says "trust me, this is a React component".  But it isn't a React component so you're going to have problems further down the line.

---

You need to somehow pass information about your store to the `JobsUtil` class, possibly through the `constructor`.  But ultimately I don't think a `class` makes sense here.  I recommend a utility hook so that you can access the current store instance through React context with the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks.

Maybe something like this:

```
export const useJobActions = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return bindActionCreators(jobActions, dispatch);
}
```

```
export const useGetJobs = () => {
  const {getJobs} = useJobActions();
  const jobsList = useSelector(state => state.jobList);

  useEffect( () => {
    if (! jobsList) {
      getJobs();
    }
  }, [getJobs, jobsList]);

  return jobsList;
}
```

---

Also, why would your `state` have a `toJS()` method?

Comment: Thank you Linda - you are correct about the `toJS()` function.
I've been looking at a way to pass the data to the utility instead, so you thank you for your suggestion